# Why the hdf5 file takes larger disk space than the space taken by pandas dataframe in memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I have a pandas dataframe that takes 4 MB of the memory:

```
>>> df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / (1024 ** 2)
>>> 3.9931907653808594
```

When I save this dataframe to hdf5 file, the space it took on disk is 21.1 MB:

```
>>> df.to_hdf('my_data.hdf5', key='df', format='table')
```

Can someone explain the reasons?

`df.info()` returns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Float64Index: 1440 entries, 1262300460.0 to 1262386800.0
Columns: 879 entries,
dtypes: category(212), float32(667)
memory usage: 4.0 MB
```

`df.dtypes.unique()` returns:

```
array([dtype('float32'),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=['Closing', 'Off'], ordered=False),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=['Active'], ordered=False),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=['-'], ordered=False),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=[], ordered=False),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=['Active', 'Off'], ordered=False),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=['Low', 'Off'], ordered=False),
       CategoricalDtype(categories=['Low'], ordered=False)], dtype=object)
```

Edit 7.24.2018, reply to @jpp

1. If I convert the categorical columns of the dataframe to integer data type, then the dataframe takes 4MB of memory. When I save it to hdf format, it takes 4.3 MB on disk.

This is how I convert categorical columns to integer datatype:

```
for col in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'category']:
    df[col] = df[col].cat.codes
```

2. If I convert the categorical columns of the dataframe to 'object' data type, then the dataframe takes 24 MB of memory. When I save it to hdf format, it takes 9.7 MB on disk.

Comment: Worth testing, are the categories being stored efficiently in HDF5? I.e. if you convert your categories to appropriate non-category types (e.g. `float`, `object`, `int`, etc), does the size increase drastically?

Comment: @jpp, that's a good idea. I did the test and post the result above. It seems that the `pd.DataFrame.to_hdf` didn't store the categorical datatype efficiently.

Comment: In your `#2. If I convert the categorical columns to object...`, do you also convert to object before savings to HDF5? Because this should be expect. Object dtype should be more expensive (9.7MB) than factorized (4.3MB). I don't see what's surprising here.